# CSS: Create custom list bullets

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there a way to create bullets using css that look like this?

[image: List with custom bullets]

Above picture best describes what I want to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you tried so far ?

Comment: Solution  https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/zhqf1f78/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/zhqf1f78/2/)
 /* HTML*/

```
        <ul>
    <li>Point one <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Point two <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </li>
    <li>Point three <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </li>
    <li>Point four <br>Lorem adipiscing elit. </li>
    <li>Point five <br> Lorem consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    </ul>
    /*CSS*/
        ul{list-style:none; padding:0}
    ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 40px;
        min-height:50px
    }
    li:last-child:after {display:none}
    ul li:after {
        content: '';
        top: 11px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        height: 100%;
        width: 2px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    ul li:before {
        content: '';
        top: 10px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        height: 2px;
        width: 30px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to draw these lines:

**Steps:**

1. Reset the default `ul` styles.
2. Add some left indent on list items to create space for custom bullets.
3. Use `:before` pseudo element to draw horizontal line.
4. Use `:after` pseudo element to draw the vertical line.
5. Clear the vertical line of list child drawn by `:after` pseudo element or draw them on all except the last one.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  font: 16px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
  background: darkgreen;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.list {
  max-width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
.list li {
  padding: 0 0 20px 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.list li:before,
.list li:not(:last-child):after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  left: -30px;
  top: 10px;
}
.list li:not(:last-child):after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
</ul>
```